# Get content of an element following element with some content

Tags: xml, xpath

I have to get values from HTML document, I can't use full xpath expression because my script would be more vulnerable in case of change in original document. Here is what the html file looks like:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="title">Kind:</div>
        <div class="value">
            <a href="http://google.com">Book</a>
        </div>

        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

The idea what I need to do to get `Book` is to get the content of the `a` subnode of the node following the node with content of `Kind:`. Can it be done with a single xpath expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this XPath:

```
//div[. = 'Kind:']/following-sibling::div/a/text()
```

It will select `div/a/text()` with preceding `div` with content `Kind:`